# How to add a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

Here's the css for post.html:

```
/* Space out content a bit */
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */
.header,
.marketing,
.footer {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

/* Custom page header */
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */
.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/* Custom page footer */
.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

/* Customize container */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 60%;
  }
}
.container-narrow > hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  padding: 14px 24px;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.marketing p + h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

How do I add a sidebar? The max-width attribute takes care of the main content at the center of the page. How do I add content to the sides? Float:right isn't working it right float's content to the right of the content in the centre and not to the right of the page.

Comment: What use is knowing the CSS without the markup?  Create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please show the relevant code you have tried. [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Maybe it's just me being a stickler, but shouldn't your header and footer classes be IDs?  You're only going to have one header and one footer on the page, I don't see the need to have them as classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if by sidebar you mean a hidden menu, or just a right column.

Right column:

```
  <div id="rightColumn">
        stuff goes here...
  </div>
```

and

```
div#rightColumn 
{
  float: right; 
  right: 15px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

...is one way.  The right-column div is in the HTML body, *not* inside any main content area div; I suspect you had it inside, which would lead to the behavior you saw.

If it's a hidden menu, you'll need Javascript; see http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples .   But you didn't have that as a tag, so I assume you mean a right or left column.